# creating a C# dll in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am creating a C# dll in visual studio express 2013. I am creating a dll for a part of my program so that it can be called whenever required. My code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

 namespace ClassLibrary2
 {
    public class take_off
    {
        UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(5556);
        IPAddress send_to =IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.1");
        IPEndPoint sending_end_point =new IPEndPoint(send_to,5556);
        int seq;
        for(int i=0;i<30;i++) 
        {
             System.Console.WriteLine("send landing command");
            string buff1= String.Format("AT*REF={0},290717696\r",seq);
            seq=seq+1;
            UdpClient.Send(buff1, sending_end_point);
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting few errors:

```
Error   1   Identifier expected 
Error   9   Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration 
Error   11  Invalid token ')' in class, struct, or interface member declaration 
Error   10  Invalid token ',' in class, struct, or interface member declaration 
Error   8   Invalid token '+' in class, struct, or interface member declaration 
Error   6   Invalid token '++' in class, struct, or interface member declaration    
Error   7   Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration 
Error   4   Invalid token '30' in class, struct, or interface member declaration    
Error   3   Invalid token 'for' in class, struct, or interface member declaration   
Error   5   Type expected   
Error   2   Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected       
Error   12  Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
```

Is there any error in the syntax I have written? I am very new to C#.
Why is the error caused?

Comment: First you need to learn syntax of c#

Comment: Sorry but can u just tell me where exactly is the error?

Comment: where is your class constructor?

Comment: Yes. Would help to learn the language. Like from reading. For example you do a lot of - method code.... outside a method. Where is the methoc? Fail to have basic class syntax.

Comment: wrap your code in a method body.

Comment: I am sorry. Thanks for the reply. Actually the error has occured as I had copied from another file.

Comment: I added a method :public static void take_off(seq).                  Now I gt an error:Identifier expected Is the method definition wrong?

Comment: @wireless_lab you can't have method with the same name as the class.

Comment: @mehow: You don't need a class constructor. C# will create one implicitly.

Comment: @DanPuzey well, it's not there is it? Were are talking about code and not Visual Studio built-in features...

Comment: @mehow: You are correct - there's no constructor defined in the code - but I don't see how that's relevant. "Where is your class constructor?" doesn't seem a useful question.

Comment: @DanPuzey since this is an add-in and I don't see any static methods I assumed that the class will need to be instantiated. Any non-abstract class in C# needs a constructor to be instantiated therefore a class constructor makes more sense to me than just having a method in there. Hope this makes it clear

Comment: @mehow: I'm not sure what you mean by "this is an add-in." Regardless, no class in C# requires that you define a constructor in code for it to be instantiated. The code presented in the OP would be a bad candidate for a constructor (you wouldn't typically send data over the network in a class constructor) and, if that code were wrapped in a method declaration, no constructor is necessary - which is why I found your original question confusing.

Comment: @DanPuzey by add-in I mean it's not a stand-alone application. you cant run a *.dll. I agree that it's a bad design-choice to put THAT code in a constructor, but the *quickest* and *dirtiest* way to get this running would be to stick it in a constructor. This would eliminate the *syntax* confusion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So many syntax mistakes. You should learn the basics before trying to do something.

### EDIT:

Here is the code you can try which has no error, it may help you to move forward. Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

 namespace ClassLibrary2
 {
    public class take_off
    {
        public void testfunction()
        {
            UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(5556);
            IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.1");
            IPEndPoint sending_end_point = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 5556);
            int seq = 0;

            for(int i=0; i<30; i++) 
            {    
                seq = seq + 1;
                System.Console.WriteLine("send landing command");
                string buff1= String.Format("AT*REF={0},290717696\r",seq);
                byte[] bytesToSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(buff1);
                udpClient.Send(bytesToSend,bytesToSend.Length,sending_end_point);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can call this testFunction in whatever code you include your DLL file. Thanks.

Comment: +1 - because it is right. We can start teaching someone too lazy to read the langauge specs the language by correcting tons of mistakes, but the better way is to tell them the truth.

Comment: Well I was going to edit it, before posting the corrected code. You shouldnt start down voting someone that fast.

Comment: Actually, only two syntax mistakes: there's no method declaration, and the call to `UdpClient.Send` needs a byte array rather than a string. It'd help everyone concerned if you tried to be more constructive with your answer.

Comment: Yes you can see the answer. I was going to spoon feed the man. Since he copy pasted the code and couldnt figure out why. But the strict behaviour will make him do some work himself before posting such questions on forums.

Comment: @Haris just FYI, TomTom, mehow, and Dan might not have seen your comment replies. When you reply to comments please use `@` followed by name to notify the other user.

Comment: @TomTom I hope you understand now.

Comment: @HarisMehmood: I'm not suggesting that you spoon feed anyone, but "So many syntax mistakes" was neither helpful nor accurate.

Answer (score 5):

You can't just put code inside your class. You need to define af method with your code in it. Like

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    //you code here
}
```